# How to avoid Transpose in output

Tags: display

I would like to have

```
a[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{HoldForm[A], i == j && i < 2}, 
         {HoldForm[A], i == j - 1}, {-HoldForm[A], 
     i == j && i >= 2}, 
         {0, True}}]; 
W = Array[a, {2, 2}]
a[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{HoldForm[Msub], i == j}, {0, True}}]; 
M = ArrayFlatten[Array[a, {2, 2}]]
TransP[M_] := Map[Transpose[#1] /. Transpose[0] -> 0 & , Transpose[M], 
       {2}]; 
G = MatrixForm[ArrayFlatten[{{M, W}, {TransP[W], 0}}]]
```

such that the Transpose[A] is printed in "Pretty" with a T in superscript in the output? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TraditionalForm` for pretty printing:

```
G//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

In **Details** section of [**documentation on Transpose**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) you can find:

[image]

and this actually is computable.

Comment: Is there away to USE StandartForm? Somehow?

Comment: If you want a traditional transpose symbol, using `StandardForm` seems pointless, and this answer is the only one that makes sense to me.